# how can I plot with multiple colors based on values on x-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

Hey guys let's say I have a pandas DataFrame

```
   Year  Delta_T
0  2000       23
1  2001       25
2  2002       22
2  2002       22
4  2004       30
5  2005       21
```

and I want to plot delta_T in function of time but I want to plot one color for the dates from 2000 to 2003 and another color from 2004 to 2005
 Can someone please tell me how I can do it?

I have tried this

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(delta_T_all.iloc[:,0].pd.Timestamp('2010-04-17'),
pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'),delta_T_all.iloc[:,1], label= '220-250m'),
plt.scatter(delta_T_all.iloc[:,0].pd.Timestamp('2016-01-01'),
pd.Timestamp('2019-09-14'),delta_T_all.iloc[:,1], label= '220-250m')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.setp(plt.gca().get_xticklabels(), rotation=60, ha="right")
plt.ylabel('Delta_T')
plt.legend()
plt.title('Delta_T in function of time')
```

Comment: You asked this before, only 4 hours earlier: [how can I plot with multiple colors based on values on x-axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60614065/how-can-i-plot-with-multiple-colors-based-on-values-on-x-axis). Please do not re-ask the exact same question.

Comment: @usr2564301   they asked me to ask it again because my question has been closed, if not I wouldn't have posted it again

Comment: They did not. "Update the question so it focuses on one problem only. This will help others answer the question. **You can edit the question.**" Your question was closed for good reasons, and you are supposed to fix those reasons so it can be re-opened.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer

```
plt.figure()
plt.scatter(delta_T_all.iloc[0:2,0],delta_T_all.iloc[0:2,1],color='r')
plt.scatter(delta_T_all.iloc[2:5,0],delta_T_all.iloc[2:5,1],color='b')
plt.xlabel('Time')
plt.ylabel('Delta_T')
plt.legend()
```